# A palavra "jamais" pode significar "sempre"?

Tags: significado, tradução

Há um livro que apresenta a seguinte citação de René Descartes sobre um problema específico da matemática:

> [1] Ouso dizer que, a meu ver, este não é apenas o problema mais útil e geral na geometria, como também é o único problema que almejo conhecer. (Cálculo: Volume 1, Larson, Hostetler e Edwards, 8ª edição, p. 95).

Por outro lado, há outro livro que apresenta a seguinte versão:

> [2] E ouso dizer que isso é não somente o problema de geometria mais útil e geral que conheço, mas também que eu jamais desejei conhecer. (História da matemática, Boyer, 1974, p. 252).

Conforme os dicionários [Michaelis](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/jamais/) e [Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/jamais), a palavra **jamais** significa: **em tempo algum**, **em nenhum  momento**, **nunca**, **sob nenhuma hipótese**. Utilizando esses significados, o final da citação [2] diz que Descartes nunca quis conhecer o problema. Porém, isso não se ajusta bem ao início da citação e também não está de acordo com a citação [1].

O original está em francês:

> [3] Et j'ose dire que c'est ceci le problème le plus utile et le plus général, non seulement que je sache, mais même que j'aie jamais désiré de savoir en géométrie. (La géométrie, René Descartes, Projeto Gutenberg, p. 24).

O original possui a seguinte tradução para o inglês:

> [4] And I dare say that this is not only the most useful and most gênerai problem in geometry
> that I know, but even that I have ever desired to know. (The geometry of René Descartes, Smith e Lathan, p. 95.)

Diante disso, parece que a palavra "jamais" em [2] foi mantida de [3] e, de acordo com [4], deveria significar "sempre". Mas não é esse o significado que os dicionários básicos apontam. Então: **Qual é o significado de "jamais" em [2]? A palavra "jamais" pode significar "sempre" em português?**

Comment: *mais até que eu tivesse querido saber em qualquer momento em geometria*. The best person I have ever known: La meilleure personne que j'ai jamais connue. A melhor pessoa que tenho conhecido em qualquer momento.

Answer (score 3):

Segundo o dicionário da [Academia Francesa](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9J0068) (l'Académie Française), a palavra ‘*jamais*’ tem dois significados, um com ‘*ne*’ (*não*) e um sozinho. Quando ‘*jamais*’ está com ‘*ne*’, ele significa o mesmo que *nunca*. Quando ‘*jamais*’ está sozinho, ele fala de um momento qualquer, como *jamais* pode referenciar em português:

> “3 algum dia, alguma vez, em algum tempo ‹se j. se lembrar de mim, escreva-me›” — [Houaiss](https://houaiss.uol.com.br/corporativo/apps/uol_www/v6-1/html/index.php), do verbete *jamais*.

Assim, provavelmente René Descartes [disse](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Page:Descartes_-_%C5%92uvres,_%C3%A9d._Adam_et_Tannery,_VI.djvu/435) algo como “[…] que eu tive o desejo de um dia saber na geometria” ou “[…] que eu já tive o desejo de saber na geometria”. É de se notar, porém, que o livro desta frase de René Descartes foi publicada em 1637; o francês talvez tenha mudado que o significado desta tenha mudado.

Ao que me parece, se isto estiver correto, as duas traduções estão certas, mas a segunda é ambígua. Pessoalmente, consegui entendê-la pelo contexto, mas me parece uma linguagem um pouco poética.

Comment: jamais, ever, em qualquer moment, como usado aqui. Que eu jamais desejei conhecer é um erro de tradução.

Answer (score 2):

Vamos lá.

Em francês, se diria:

La meilleure personne que j'ai **jamais** connu.

Tradução em português: A melhor pessoa que tenho conhecido **em qualquer momento**.

Larousse: **jamais**

1. Sans négation, indique un temps quelconque, dans le passé ou le futur : Si jamais je te revois. Pire que jamais.

**Sem negação, indica um tempo qualquer, no passado ou no futuro.**

"[...] mais même que j'aie jamais désiré de savoir en géométrie."

tradução:
"[...] mais até que eu tivesse querido saber em qualquer momento en geometria."

Answer (score 1):

Encontrei uma [referência](https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/jamais) com a acepção *"até então"*.

Veja o exemplo:

> Esta é a melhor oportunidade jamais vista!

Que pode ser reescrito como

> Esta é a melhor oportunidade vista até então!

Ou

> Esta é a melhor oportunidade vista até o momento!

Ou (e acredito que seja a forma mais comum atualmente no Brasil):

> Esta é a melhor oportunidade já vista!

Este [dicionário](https://www.dicio.com.br/jamais/) inclui o sinônimo *"já"*.

A frase que você forneceu poderia ser simplificada como

> Este não é só o problema mais útil que eu conheço, como também o mais útil que eu já desejei conhecer.